# Why is my transaction deadlocking in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

I am using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate to create a transaction like this:

```
@Autowired
private PingRepository repository;

@Transactional
public void processPing(Ping ping)
{
    Ping storedPing = repository.findById(ping.id);

    if (storedPing == null)
    {
        repository.save(ping);
    } else
    {
        if (ping.lastProcessTime > storedPing.lastProcessTime)
        {
            storedPing.setLastProcessTime(ping.lastProcessTime);
        }
    }
}

public interface PingRepository extends CrudRepository<Ping, PingKey>
{
    @Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
    Ping findById(PingKey id);
}
```

While most of the time the above code succeeds, I also see a ton of exceptions like these:

```
caused by com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException:
Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
com.dripstat.alerts.app.store.PingOps$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4b6adccb.processPing(<generated>)
<more stacktrace....>
```

This is the only place where the `Ping` table is updated.

How can the `processPing()` method above possibly run into a deadlock?

**Update:**

Here is some relevant output from `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` command:

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2015-12-23 05:57:47 7f23d73c6700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 32990178, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 3 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 314344, OS thread handle 0x7f23d6480700, query id 99645000 104.197.97.45 dsprod update
insert into pings (lastProcessTime, id, type) values (1450845, '52c7e28eebb26a86fb1505b5', 'INCIDENT')
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 17 page no 4 n bits 376 index `PRIMARY` of table `alerts`.`pings` trx id 32990178 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 24; hex 353363336635646430636632336133633062623934613866; asc 53c3f5dd0cf23a3c0bb94a8f;;
 1: len 3; hex 415050; asc APP;;
 2: len 6; hex 000001f76076; asc     `v;;
 3: len 7; hex 5a000001e10b80; asc Z      ;;
 4: len 4; hex d67a36f8; asc  z6 ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 32990184, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
3 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 2 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 314341, OS thread handle 0x7f23d73c6700, query id 99645014 104.197.97.45 dsprod update
insert into pings (lastProcessTime, id, type) values (1450848, '52c7e28eebb26a86fb1505b5', 'INCIDENT')
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 17 page no 4 n bits 376 index `PRIMARY` of table `alerts`.`pings` trx id 32990184 lock_mode X locks gap before rec
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 24; hex 353363336635646430636632336133633062623934613866; asc 53c3f5dd0cf23a3c0bb94a8f;;
 1: len 3; hex 415050; asc APP;;
 2: len 6; hex 000001f76076; asc     `v;;
 3: len 7; hex 5a000001e10b80; asc Z      ;;
 4: len 4; hex d67a36f8; asc  z6 ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 17 page no 4 n bits 376 index `PRIMARY` of table `alerts`.`pings` trx id 32990184 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 3 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 5; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 24; hex 353363336635646430636632336133633062623934613866; asc 53c3f5dd0cf23a3c0bb94a8f;;
 1: len 3; hex 415050; asc APP;;
 2: len 6; hex 000001f76076; asc     `v;;
 3: len 7; hex 5a000001e10b80; asc Z      ;;
 4: len 4; hex d67a36f8; asc  z6 ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

Comment: By not using pessimistic locks, those lead to database locks, depending on your db that might turn into table locks.

Comment: i dont understand you. are you saying the pessimistic lock in 'findById' is causing this issue?

Comment: Yes as that leads to locking the database, when a thread has a lock another thread cannot have a lock and hence looses.

Comment: but isnt the whole point of a lock that other thread will wait?

Comment: That depends on your settings (timeout) and how your database behaves.

Comment: what you are describing seems to be a 'lock timeout'. however what is happening here is a 'deadlock' which requires a circular dependency between 2 transactions. as you can see in the code above there is no circular dependency in the execution

Comment: Actually we *cannot* see that. We'd need to know all places where this piece of code is called and **all paths inside one transaction** where this is  called. I suppose you have more than 1 table? Then you might have a transaction like : (insert ping, update foo, update ping) and another (update foo, update ping). If these two interlock, you'd have the second holding lock on foo (waiting for ping) and the first holding lock on ping (waiting for foo) -> deadlock

Comment: as i mentiond, this is indeed the only place pings is accesed from. thus you do in fact see the full and only transaction using the ping table

Answer (score 0):

the code is semantically correct.
this is a bug in mysql. 
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=48911